# Is it possible to determine whether the sequence $\,a_0=p,\;a_{n+1}=(a_n-2)\cdot a_n+2\,$ will reach another prime number?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers, sequences-and-series

Given a prime $\,p\,$ let's consider the following sequence:

$a_0=p$

$a_{n+1}=(a_n-2)\cdot a_n+2$

> **Is it possible to determine whether the sequence $\,a_n\,$ will reach, sooner or later, another prime number?**

Some examples:

for $\,p=2$, $\;\;a_1=2\;\;$ (prime)

for $\,p=3$, $\;\;a_1=5\;\;$ (prime)

for $\,p=29$, $\;\;a_2=614657\;\;$ (prime)

for $\,p=31$, $\;\;a_5=185302018885184100000000000000000000000000000001\;\;$ (prime)

Many thanks.

---

[ **Added** ]

Experimental evidence shows that, up to 100, only for the following prime numbers $\,p\,$ the sequence $\,a_n\,$ should never reach another prime:
$$13,19,23,43,53,59,61,71,73,79$$
In order to find out the possible divisors of $\,a_n=(p-1)^{2^n}+1\,$ (see the answer of [GH from MO](https://mathoverflow.net/users/11919/gh-from-mo)) the following result can be exploited:

**the only prime divisors of $\,a_n\,$ are of the form $\,k\cdot2^{n+1}+1$.**

Example:
$$(13-1)^8+1=17\cdot97\cdot260753=(1\cdot2^4+1)\cdot(6\cdot2^4+1)\cdot(16297\cdot2^4+1)$$

Comment: Notice that we can't even establish the infinitude of primes of the form $n^2+1$, let alone with the added condition of $n$ being a power of $p-1$.

Comment: @GjergjiZaimi: I think this question is slightly different. I suspect that there exists a prime $p$ such that $a_n$ is never prime, but probably we will never be able to decide this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question can be reformulated as follows.

**Question.** If $p$ is a prime, does there always exist a positive integer $n$ such that $(p-1)^{2^n}+1$ is also a prime?

I believe that this question is out of reach at present (my guess is that the answer is "no", but we will never know). Similar to the well-known questions on [Fermat numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat_number) and its [generalizations](https://primes.utm.edu/glossary/page.php?sort=GeneralizedFermatNumber).

Comment: Maybe did you want to write $(p-1)^{2n}+1$?

Comment: @AugustoSanti: For $p=31$, your $a_5$ is $30^{32}+1$, not $30^{10}+1$. In general, your $a_n$ is $(p-1)^{2^n}+1$, as I wrote. The exponents are $2$-powers.

Comment: Sorry ... you're absolutely right

Comment: For example if p is a Fermat prime, the OP asks if there exists a bigger Fermat prime. This is a well known open problem for $p=2^{16}+1$.

Comment: @MarkSapir: Excellent point!